# Why am I able to use methods defined in one class in another separate class?

Tags: javascript, class, methods, linked-list, nodes

Here I have two classes, the Node class, and the LinkedList class. I am wondering why I'm able to use methods from the Node class inside of the LinkedList class.

For example, in the LinkedList class, in the .addToTail() method, I use the .setNextNode() and .getNextNode() methods on the tail variable which is initialized to "this.head". Since "this.head" isn't an instance of the Node class, it shouldn't be able to use methods in the Node class, right...? Or am I missing something?

```
class Node {
    constructor(data) {
        this.data = data;
        this.next = null;
    }
    getNextNode() {
        return this.next;
    }
    setNextNode(node) {
        if (node instanceof Node || node === null) {
            this.next = node;
        } else {
            throw new Error('Error!');
        }
    }
}

class LinkedList {
    constructor() {
        this.head = null;
    }
    addToHead(data) {
        let newHead = new Node(data);
        let currentHead = this.head;
        this.head = newHead;
        if (currentHead) {
            this.head.setNextNode(currentHead);
        }
    }
    addToTail(data) {
        let tail = this.head;
        if (!tail) {
          this.head = new Node(data);
        } else {
          while(tail.getNextNode()) {
            tail = tail.getNextNode()
          }
          tail.setNextNode(new Node(data));
        }
      }
}
```

Comment: _"Since "this.head" isn't an instance of the Node class, it shouldn't be able to use methods in the Node class, right..."_ - Although `this.head` starts off as `null`, your code sets it to a Node instance with `this.head = new Node(data)` and with `this.head = newHead`

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it really helped me understand!

Answer (score 0):

You are able to use them because you have an instance of a Node that you assign to head. You haven't added any access modifiers (e.g private) that could set restrictions on the use of those functions.

Comment: The question is tagged as `javascript`: JavaScript (contrary to TypeScript) does not have access modifiers, like `private`. However, it does have a syntax for [private fields](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/Private_class_fields).

Answer (score 0):

newHead is an instance of Node. Setting this.head equal to newHead means that this.head is also now an instance of Node. You can see this by checking this.head with 'instanceof'.

```
addToHead(data) {
   let newHead = newNode(data);
   let currentHead = this.head;
   this.head = newHead;
   console.log(this.head instanceof Node); // returns true
   . . .
}
```